# Solving a nonlinear system of two equations with two unknowns using Newton's method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the function $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $$g(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix} x\\ x^2 + y^2-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and the non-linear system of equations

$$g(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Newton's method takes the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_{n+1}\\ y_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_{n}\\ y_{n} \end{pmatrix}-Dg(x_{n},y_{n})^{-1}g(x_{n},y_{n}).$$

Given the starting point $(x_{0},y_{0})=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, how do I compute the next iterate $(x_{1},y_{1})$ via Newton's method?

I obtain $(x_{1},y_{1})=(0,3/2)$, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: which second line?

Comment: The associated non-linear system of equations

Comment: do you mind showing your ''calculation'' I don't quite follow

Comment: Are you sure the associated nonlinear system of equations is correct because there are no equations there? Something is missing.

Comment: @Djhoe: I have edited your title and reformated your question without changing the content. Have a look at the LaTeX code. Feel free to roll back the edit if you like. Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular Newton-Raphson method is initialized with a starting point $x_0$ and then you iterate $\tag 1x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

In higher dimensions, there is an exact analog. We define:

$$\tag 2 F\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x,y) \\  f_2(x,y)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\   x^2+y^2 -1  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

The derivative of this system is the $2x2$ Jacobian given by:

$$\tag 3 J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 2x & 2y   \end{bmatrix}$$

The function $G$ is defined as:

$$\tag 4 G(x) = x - J(x)^{-1}F(x)$$

and the functional Newton-Raphson method for nonlinear systems is given by the iteration procedure that evolves from selecting an initial $x^{(0)}$ and generating for $k \ge 1$ (compare this to $(1)$),

$$x^{(k)} = G(x^{(k-1)}) = x^{(k-1)} - J(x^{(k-1)})^{-1}F(x^{(k-1)}).$$

We can write this as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k)}\\x_2^{(k)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k-1)}\\x_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}y_1^{(k-1)}\\y_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}$$

where:

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1^{(k-1)}\\y_2^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}= -\left(J\left(x_1^{(k-1)},x_2^{(k-1)}\right)\right)^{-1}F\left(x_1^{(k-1)},x_2^{(k-1)}\right)$$

Using the starting vector:

$$x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}x^{(0)}\\y^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5\\0.5\end{bmatrix}$$

The iterates are

- $(0.5, 0.5), (0., 1.5), (0., 1.0833333333333333), (0., 1.0032051282051282), (0., 1.0000051200131073), (0., 1.000000000013107), (0., 1.)$

By inspection, we can see that the zero should be

$$(x, y) = (0, 1)$$

In other words, for this initial condition, we have converged to the correct solution. Of course, for a different starting vector you may get a different solution and perhaps no solution at all.

Comment: thanks it seems like I was able to find the right iterated $x_{1}$ value then now how do I obtain the right $y_{1}$ value? I used the equations, And my textbook only shows me how to find $x_{1}$ but it wont show me how to find $y_{1}$

Comment: You just find $$-J^{-1}~F$$ at each iteration point. You know $J$ and $F$ and just negate the evaluation of the inverse of $J$ times $F$ at each iteration point.Clear?

Comment: so that should be \begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 0 \\
1/2 & -1/2 
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: @Djhoe: $\vec x^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}x^{(0)}\\y^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} -J(x^{(0)},y^{(0)})^{-1}F(x^{(0)},y^{(0)}) = \left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^T-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 \dfrac{2}{2} & \dfrac{2}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}.\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2-1\right)^T = \left(0,\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^T$

Answer (score 1):

Ok If I am not totally mistaken

$(x_{0},y_{0})=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$

$\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{n+1}\\
y_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{n}\\
y_{n}
\end{pmatrix}-(D_{g}(x_{n},y_{n}))^{-1}g(x_{n},y_{n})$

=$\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{1}\\
y_{1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{0}\\
y_{0}
\end{pmatrix}-(D_{g}(x_{0},y_{0}))^{-1}g(x_{0},y_{0})$

=$\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$

=(0,3/2)

and from here how do we get $(x_{1},y_{1})=(0,1)$? :i...

Comment: Okay now everything seems very obvious thanks a lot for you patience ;)

Comment: sorry I am looking at this question again now. It seems like your iterations are just finding $(x_{2},y_{2})$ and then find $(x_{3},y_{3})$. and since $y_{n}$ converges to 1 then we get (0,1). But doing this way we do not find the iteration (0,1) we get that $(x_{1},y_{1})=(0, 3/2)$. So I am a little bit confused that when we find higher value iterations we just say that the value that they converge to are $(x_{1},y_{2})$=$(x_{converge},y_{converge})$. But if this is the case then $(x_{1},y_{1})$=$(x_{2},y_{2})$=$(x_{3},y_{3})$......=$(x_{n},y_{n})$

Comment: So if the task is to find the value of take example $(x_{7},y_{7})$ we just say that it is the same as $(x_{1},y_{1})$ Because we only care about the infinite tail?

Comment: because you do six iterations and then you say well y must converge 1. but this you can see when you have computed up to $(x_{6},y_{6}$ and  $(x_{6},y_{6}) \neq (x_{1},y_{1})$ but even though this is not the case you conclude that $y_{1}=1$ because $y_{n}=1$

Comment: But I am looking specifically for $(x_{1},y_{1})$ so what i think is that then no matter which iterative you're looking for you only look for the ''infinite tail''?

Comment: Yes that i what i wanted to understand, so I am confused because I was doing a multiple choice exam preparation and this answer is not a part of the ones you can pick :¨¨)

Comment: Given the starting point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ compute the next iterate $(x_{1},y_{1})$ via newton's method.. a) (2,-1)  b) (0,5,-1) c) (0,1) d) (1,2)

Comment: Yep, that was just to calculate one iterate, so the result in that case is $(x_1, y_1)$. Please add the original problem too, exactly as it is written - something seems wrong.

Comment: Okay it is updated now thanks